# reactjs with tailwindcss using webpack module

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm new to using tailwindcss in reactJS. I still didn't get the tailwindcss class styles in my UI.

In tailwindplay link it is working fine but not in my local.

anyone help me out guys....

these are the npm's i've installed in my react application

```
npm install tailwindcss  postcss autoprefixer css-loader style-loader postcss-loader babel-loader webpack webpack-cli webpack-dev-server react react-dom
```

```
npx tailwindcss init
```

**App.js**

```
import '../src/styles/tailwind.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold underline">
    Hello wqoprld!
  </h1>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**in tailwind.css**

```
/* src/styles/tailwind.css */
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';

/* Add your custom styles here */
```

**in postcss.config.css**

```
// postcss.config.js
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
      tailwindcss: {},
      autoprefixer: {},
    },
  };
```

**in tailwind.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
    theme: {
      extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
  }
```

**in Package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.15",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.28",
    "postcss-loader": "^7.3.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "webpack": "^5.88.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1"
  },
```

in my local desktop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hv0pn.png)

in the tailwindplay weblink

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRp28.png)

Comment: Consider checking `App.js` is covered by the `content` file globs in the Tailwind configuration. Consider using the `@tailwind` directives instead of `@import`ing. Consider the `import` path to `tailwind.css` in `App.js` is correct.

Comment: i also tried that one. but still tailwind css is not working in my local

`/* src/styles/tailwind.css */
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

/* Add your custom styles here */`

Comment: Consider checking `App.js` is covered by the `content` file globs in the Tailwind configuration. Consider checking the `import` path to `tailwind.css` in `App.js` is correct.